# Set value when doing UNION ALL in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, union

I'm doing a UNION ALL on two different tables. the query works great but I need to set an extra column called `tab` that is either 1 or 2 telling from which table.

example query:

```
SELECT * FROM news
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM highlight
```

in my php code I will do $row['tab']==1 then its news..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *, 1 AS `tab` FROM news
UNION ALL
SELECT *, 2 AS `tab` FROM highlight
```